# Are the days of passing const std::string & as a parameter over?

Tags: c++, c++11

I heard a recent talk by Herb Sutter who suggested that the reasons to pass `std::vector` and `std::string` by `const &` are largely gone.  He suggested that writing a function such as the following is now preferable:

```
std::string do_something ( std::string inval )
{
   std::string return_val;
   // ... do stuff ...
   return return_val;
}
```

I understand that the `return_val` will be an rvalue at the point the function returns and can therefore be returned using move semantics, which are very cheap.  However, `inval` is still much larger than the size of a reference (which is usually implemented as a pointer).  This is because a `std::string` has various components including a pointer into the heap and a member `char[]` for short string optimization.  So it seems to me that passing by reference is still a good idea.

Can anyone explain why Herb might have said this?

Comment: I think the best answer to the question is probably to read Dave Abrahams's [article about it on C++ Next](https://web.archive.org/web/20140113221447/http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/). I'd add that I see nothing about this that qualifies as off-topic or not constructive. It's a clear question, about programming, to which there are factual answers.

Comment: Fascinating, so if you're going to have to make a copy anyway, pass-by-value is likely faster than pass-by-reference.

Comment: @Sz.  I am sensitive to questions being falsely categorized as duplicates and closed.  I do not remember the details of this case and have not re-reviewed them.  Instead I am simply going to delete my comment on the assumption that I made a mistake.  Thank you for bringing this to my attention.

Comment: @HowardHinnant, thank you very much, it's always a precious moment when one comes across this level of attentiveness and sensibility, it's so refreshing! (I'll delete mine then, of course.)

Comment: Since the introduction of `std::string_view` there's never a good case for passing a reference to string.  But given when you asked this question, that's probably not what you're looking for!

Answer (score 441, accepted):

The reason Herb said what he said is because of cases like this.

Let's say I have function `A` which calls function `B`, which calls function `C`. And `A` passes a string through `B` and into `C`. `A` does not know or care about `C`; all `A` knows about is `B`. That is, `C` is an implementation detail of `B`.

Let's say that A is defined as follows:

```
void A()
{
  B("value");
}
```

If B and C take the string by `const&`, then it looks something like this:

```
void B(const std::string &str)
{
  C(str);
}

void C(const std::string &str)
{
  //Do something with `str`. Does not store it.
}
```

All well and good. You're just passing pointers around, no copying, no moving, everyone's happy. `C` takes a `const&` because it doesn't store the string. It simply uses it.

Now, I want to make one simple change: `C` needs to store the string somewhere.

```
void C(const std::string &str)
{
  //Do something with `str`.
  m_str = str;
}
```

Hello, copy constructor and potential memory allocation (ignore the [Short String Optimization (SSO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10315041/meaning-of-acronym-sso-in-the-context-of-stdstring)). C++11's move semantics are supposed to make it possible to remove needless copy-constructing, right? And `A` passes a temporary; there's no reason why `C` should have to *copy* the data. It should just abscond with what was given to it.

Except it can't. Because it takes a `const&`.

If I change `C` to take its parameter by value, that just causes `B` to do the copy into that parameter; I gain nothing.

So if I had just passed `str` by value through all of the functions, relying on `std::move` to shuffle the data around, we wouldn't have this problem. If someone wants to hold on to it, they can. If they don't, oh well.

Is it more expensive? Yes; moving into a value is more expensive than using references. Is it less expensive than the copy? Not for small strings with SSO. Is it worth doing?

It depends on your use case. How much do you hate memory allocations?

Comment: When you say that moving into a value is more expensive than using references, that's still more expensive by a constant amount (independent of the length of the string being moved) right?

Comment: @NeilG : That depends whether the standard library implementation uses small-string-optimization, and if so, what that small-string buffer size is.

Comment: @ildjarn: It shouldn't have anything to do with small strings since there must be some constant k such that all small strings can be copied in less k time.

Comment: @NeilG : I doubt the implementation would copy the contents of the unused small-string buffer if the actual string data length exceeds that buffer size.

Comment: @ildjarn: it doesn't matter because the buffer still has a fixed maximum size.

Comment: @NeilG : It _could_ matter because the data inside the small-string buffer could be copied conditionally. This just goes back to "it depends".

Comment: @ildjarn: Do you know how order analysis works?  I'm saying that it's O(1) to move a string.  It doesn't depend on small strings.

Comment: @NeilG : Do you understand what "implementation-dependent" means? What you're saying is wrong, because it depends on _if and how_ SSO is implemented.

Comment: @ildjarn:  In order analysis, if the worst case of something is bound by a constant, then it's still constant time.  Is there not a longest small string?  Doesn't that string take some constant amount of time to copy?  Don't all smaller strings take less time to copy?  Then, string copying for small strings is "constant time" in order analysis — despite small strings taking varying amounts of time to copy.  Order analysis is concerned with *asymptotic behaviour*.

Comment: @NeilG : Sure, but your **original** question was "*that's still more expensive by a constant amount (independent of the length of the string being moved) right?*" The point I'm trying to make is, it could be more expensive by _different_ constant amounts depending on the length of the string, which gets summed up as "no".

Comment: passing by values is cheap for rvalues but with the same example for lvalues,`string s= "value"; B(s);` will do 3 copies. So I guess best solution would be to have two overloads, one for lvalue ref and other for rvalue ref.

Comment: @balki: Where do you get 3 copies from? The literal is copied into `s`, and `s` is copied into the parameter of `B`. So where does the third one come from?

Comment: @NicolBolas From `B` it is copied to `C` and inside `C` it is copied into `m_str`

Comment: @balki: No it isn't. The above definitions for `B` and `C` take their value by `const&`. And the proposed ones that take their value by value will *move* their values from their arguments to the various destinations. So no copying will take place.

Comment: @NicolBolas Yes, I understand with `const&`, there are no copies but when it is replaced with value as shown in the question, there will be 0 copies for an rvalue but 2 copies for an lvalue(last one can be moved).

Comment: @balki: First, that still doesn't explain where you get "will do 3 copies" from, unless you're backtracking on that. Second, yes, if the user does not move an l-value into the parameter, then it will be copied. If the function is going to copy the string to some internal object anyway, at least this way, the user decides if it will be a copy or a move. Which is the whole point of my answer.

Comment: Potential error in the answer. Perhaps this answer should say 'copy assign' rather than 'copy construct'. If you're going to copy *construct* from a `const &` argument, then it might be simpler and better to take it by value. But if you're going to copy *assign*, then alternatives might be better. Either way, before we debate, let's distinguish copy-construct and copy-assign

Comment: Sorry to nitpick, but you don't specify the type of m_str anywhere in your example. If it were a `const std::string&`, there would be no copy constructor, no overhead. If you make its type explicit, your answer will be more comprehensible to those new to C++.

Comment: Has nobody pointed out that by this reasoning, passing by `&` is the best of both passing by `const&` and by `std::move`? It's faster than `std::move`, but still allows `C` to optionally steal the string. (the only disadvantage is not being able to pass in a temporary, which is the point of the question, I admit).

Comment: Why would the string be `moved` from B to C in the by value case? If B is `B(std::string b)` and C is `C(std::string c)` then either we have to call `C(std::move(b))` in B or `b` has to remain unchanged (thus 'unmoved from') until exiting `B`. (Perhaps an optimizing compiler will move the string under the as-if rule if `b` isn't used after the call but I don't think there is a strong guarantee.) The same is true for the copy of `str` to `m_str`. Even if a function paramter was initialized with an rvalue it is an lvalue inside the function and `std::move` is required to move from that lvalue.

Comment: "So if I had just passed str by value through all of the functions, relying on std::move to shuffle the data around, ..."  Perhaps you could show the better version you have in mind, including where the std::moves would be placed?  It's not obvious.

Answer (score 183):

> Are the days of passing const std::string & as a parameter over?

**No**. Many people take this advice (including Dave Abrahams) beyond the domain it applies to, and simplify it to apply to *all* `std::string` parameters -- *Always* passing `std::string` by value is not a "best practice" for any and all arbitrary parameters and applications because the optimizations these talks/articles focus on apply *only to a restricted set of cases*.

If you're returning a value, mutating the parameter, or taking the value, then passing by value could save expensive copying and offer syntactical convenience.

As ever, passing by const reference saves much copying *when you don't need a copy*.

Now to the specific example:

> However inval is still quite a lot larger than the size of a reference (which is usually implemented as a pointer). This is because a std::string has various components including a pointer into the heap and a member char[] for short string optimization. So it seems to me that passing by reference is still a good idea. Can anyone explain why Herb might have said this?

If stack size is a concern (and assuming this is not inlined/optimized), `return_val` + `inval` > `return_val` -- IOW, peak stack usage can be *reduced* by passing by value here (note: oversimplification of ABIs). Meanwhile, passing by const reference can disable the optimizations. The primary reason here is not to avoid stack growth, but to ensure the optimization can be performed *where it is applicable*.

The days of passing by const reference aren't over -- the rules just more complicated than they once were. If performance is important, you'll be wise to consider how you pass these types, based on the details you use in your implementations.

Comment: On stack usage, typical ABIs will pass a single reference in a register with no stack usage.

Answer (score 71):

Short answer: **NO!** Long answer:

- **If you won't modify the string (treat is as read-only), pass it as `const ref&`.**
  *(the `const ref&` obviously needs to stay within scope while the function that uses it executes)*
- **If you plan to modify it or you know it will get out of scope *(threads)*, pass it as a `value`, don't copy the `const ref&` inside your function body.**

There was a post on **cpp-next.com** called [**"Want speed, pass by value!"**](http://web.archive.org/web/20120908071416/http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value). The TL;DR:

> **Guideline**: Don’t copy your function arguments. Instead, pass them by value and let the compiler do the copying.

**TRANSLATION of ^**

**Don’t copy your function arguments** --- means: *if you plan to modify the argument value by copying it to an internal variable, just use a value argument instead*.

So, **don't do this**:

```
std::string function(const std::string& aString){
    auto vString(aString);
    vString.clear();
    return vString;
}
```

**do this**:

```
std::string function(std::string aString){
    aString.clear();
    return aString;
}
```

When you need to modify the argument value in your function body.

*You just need to be aware how you plan to use the argument in the function body. Read-only or NOT... and if it sticks within scope.*

Comment: You recommend passing by reference in some cases, but you point to a guideline that recommends always passing by value.

Comment: @KeithThompson **Don’t copy your function arguments.** Means don't copy the `const ref&` to an internal variable to modify it. If you need to modify it... make the parameter a value. It's rather clear for my non-English speaking self.

Comment: The guideline you quote specifically says "pass them by value", which would seem to contradict your recommendation to use `const ref&` (your first bullet point).

Comment: @KeithThompson The **Guideline** quote *(Don’t copy your function arguments. Instead, pass them by value and let the compiler do the copying.)* is COPIED from that page. If that's not clear enough, I can't help. I don't fully trust compilers to make the best choices. I'd rather be very clear about my intents in the way I define function arguments. #1 If it's read-only, it's a `const ref&`. #2 If I need to write it or I know it gets out of scope... I use a value. #3 If I need to modify the original value, I pass by `ref&`. #4 I use `pointers *` if an argument is optional so I can `nullptr` it.

Comment: I'm not taking sides on the question of whether to pass by value or by reference. My point is that you advocate passing by reference in some cases, but then cite (seemingly to support your position) a guideline that recommends always passing by value. If you disagree with the guideline, you might want to say so and explain why. (The links to cpp-next.com aren't working for me.)

Comment: Web Archive copy of article: https://web.archive.org/web/20140113221447/http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/

Comment: @KeithThompson: You're mis-paraphrasing the guideline.  It is not to "always" pass by value.  To summarize, it was "If you would have made a local copy, use pass by value to have the compiler perform that copy for you."  It's not saying to use pass-by-value when you weren't going to make a copy.

Answer (score 66):

This highly depends on the compiler's implementation.

However, it also depends on what you use.

Lets consider next functions :

```
bool foo1( const std::string v )
{
  return v.empty();
}
bool foo2( const std::string & v )
{
  return v.empty();
}
```

These functions are implemented in a separate compilation unit in order to avoid inlining. Then :
1. If you pass a literal to these two functions, you will not see much difference in performances. In both cases, a string object has to be created
2. If you pass another std::string object, `foo2` will outperform `foo1`, because `foo1` will do a deep copy.

On my PC, using g++ 4.6.1, I got these results :

- variable by reference: 1000000000 iterations -> time elapsed: 2.25912 sec
- variable by value: 1000000000 iterations -> time elapsed: 27.2259 sec
- literal by reference: 100000000 iterations -> time elapsed: 9.10319 sec
- literal by value: 100000000 iterations -> time elapsed: 8.62659 sec

Comment: Of course for 2. you specifically mean a string lvalue.  If the function primarily handles tempories, returned from other functions for example then it'll be a different story.

Comment: What's more relevant is what's happening _inside_ the function: _would it, if called with a reference, need to make a copy internally that can be omitted when passing by value_?

Comment: @Benj Yes, I meant lvalue std::string

Comment: @leftaroundabout Yes, off course. My assumption that both functions are doing exactly the same thing.

Comment: That's not my point. Whether passing by value or by reference is better depends on what you're doing inside the function. In your example, you're not actually using much of the string object, so reference is _obviously_ better. But if the function's task were to place the string in some struct or to perform, say, some recursive algorithm involving multiple splits of the string, passing by value might actually _save_ some copying, compared to passing by reference. Nicol Bolas explains it quite well.

Comment: `using g++ 4.6.1` - what optimization settings?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft I used `-O3`, but the similar results are for other settings.

Comment: To me "it depends on what you do inside the function" is bad design - since you are basing the signature of the function on the internals of the implementation.

Comment: Might be a typo, but the last two literal timings have 10x fewer loops.

Comment: @TankorSmash or he preferred to wait 9 seconds instead of 90.

Comment: so, using string_view arguments saves us a copy of std::string in case of `B("value")` since it delays the construction of a `std::string` but what about `B(getTempStdString())`? looks like the Herb suggestion still wins for that use case.

Answer (score 44):

Unless you actually need a copy it's still reasonable to take `const &`. For example:

```
bool isprint(std::string const &s) {
    return all_of(begin(s),end(s),(bool(*)(char))isprint);
}
```

If you change this to take the string by value then you'll end up moving or copying the parameter, and there's no need for that. Not only is copy/move likely more expensive, but it also introduces a new potential failure; the copy/move could throw an exception (e.g., allocation during copy could fail) whereas taking a reference to an existing value can't.

If you *do* need a copy then passing and returning by value is usually (always?) the best option. In fact I generally wouldn't worry about it in C++03 unless you find that extra copies actually causes a performance problem. Copy elision seems pretty reliable on modern compilers. I think people's skepticism and insistence that you have to check your table of compiler support for RVO is mostly obsolete nowadays.

---

In short, C++11 doesn't really change anything in this regard except for people that didn't trust copy elision.

Comment: Move constructors are typically implemented with `noexcept`, but copy constructors obviously aren't.

Answer (score 38):

Almost.

In C++17, we have `basic_string_view<?>`, which brings us down to basically one narrow use case for `std::string const&` parameters.

The existence of move semantics has eliminated one use case for `std::string const&` -- if you are planning on storing the parameter, taking a `std::string` by value is more optimal, as you can `move` out of the parameter.

If someone called your function with a raw C `"string"` this means only one `std::string` buffer is ever allocated, as opposed to two in the `std::string const&` case.

However, if you don't intend to make a copy, taking by `std::string const&` is still useful in C++14.

With `std::string_view`, so long as you aren't passing said string to an API that expects C-style `'\0'`-terminated character buffers, you can more efficiently get `std::string` like functionality without risking any allocation.  A raw C string can even be turned into a `std::string_view` without any allocation or character copying.

At that point, the use for `std::string const&` is when you aren't copying the data wholesale, and are going to pass it on to a C-style API that expects a null terminated buffer, and you need the higher level string functions that `std::string` provides.  In practice, this is a rare set of requirements.

Comment: I appreciate this answer – but I do want to point out it that it does suffer (as many quality answers do) from a bit of domain-specific bias. To wit: “In practice, this is a rare set of requirements”… in my own development experience, these constraints – which seem abnormally narrow to the author – are met, like, literally all the time. It’s worth pointing this out.

Comment: @fish2000 To be clear, for `std::string` to dominate you don't just need *some* of those requirements but *all* of them.  Any one or even two of those is, I'd admit, common.  Maybe you do commonly need all 3 (like, you are doing some parsing of a string argument to pick which C API you are going to pass it wholesale to?)

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont It is a YMMV thing – but it’s a frequent use-case if (say) you are programming against POSIX, or other APIs where C-string semantics are, like, the lowest common denominator. I should say really that I love `std::string_view` – as you point out, “A raw C string can even be turned into a std::string_view without any allocation or character copying” which is something worth remembering to those who are using C++ in the context of such API usage, indeed.

Comment: @fish2000 "'A raw C string can even be turned into a std::string_view without any allocation or character copying' which is something worth remembering".  Indeed, but it leaves out the best part-- in the case that the raw string is a string literal, *it doesn't even require a runtime strlen()*!

Comment: The BEST answer of this question.

Comment: Although I still want to ask another question. @Yakk-AdamNevraumont

What about using the perfect forwarding? For example, `void f(std::string&& s) { std::string copy = std::forward(s)}` ?

Comment: @Bob That isn't taking `std::string` by `const&`, so I don't see how it applies to this answer?

Answer (score 18):

`std::string` is not [Plain Old Data(POD)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146452/what-are-pod-types-in-c), and its raw size is not the most relevant thing ever. For example, if you pass in a string which is above the length of SSO and allocated on the heap, I would expect the copy constructor to not copy the SSO storage.

The reason this is recommended is because `inval` is constructed from the argument expression, and thus is always moved or copied as appropriate- there is no performance loss, assuming that you need ownership of the argument. If you don't, a `const` reference could still be the better way to go.

Comment: Interesting point about the copy constructor being smart enough not to worry about the SSO if it's not using it.  Probably correct, I'm going to have to check if that's true ;-)

Comment: @Benj: Old comment I know, but if SSO is small enough copying it unconditionally is faster than doing a conditional branch. For example, 64 bytes is a cache line and can be copied in a really trivial amount of time. Probably 8 cycles or less on x86_64.

Comment: Even if the SSO is not copied by the copy constructor, an `std::string<>` is 32 bytes that are allocated from the stack, 16 of which need to be initialized. Compare this to just 8 bytes allocated and initialized for a reference: It is twice the amount of CPU work, and it takes up four times as much cache space that won't be available to other data.

Comment: Oh, and I forgot to talk about passing function arguments in registers; that would bring the stack usage of the reference down to zero for the last callee...

Answer (score 17):

I've copy/pasted the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9952622/576911) here, and changed the names and spelling to fit this question.

Here is code to measure what is being asked:

```
#include <iostream>

struct string
{
    string() {}
    string(const string&) {std::cout << "string(const string&)\n";}
    string& operator=(const string&) {std::cout << "string& operator=(const string&)\n";return *this;}
#if (__has_feature(cxx_rvalue_references))
    string(string&&) {std::cout << "string(string&&)\n";}
    string& operator=(string&&) {std::cout << "string& operator=(string&&)\n";return *this;}
#endif

};

#if PROCESS == 1

string
do_something(string inval)
{
    // do stuff
    return inval;
}

#elif PROCESS == 2

string
do_something(const string& inval)
{
    string return_val = inval;
    // do stuff
    return return_val; 
}

#if (__has_feature(cxx_rvalue_references))

string
do_something(string&& inval)
{
    // do stuff
    return std::move(inval);
}

#endif

#endif

string source() {return string();}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "do_something with lvalue:\n\n";
    string x;
    string t = do_something(x);
#if (__has_feature(cxx_rvalue_references))
    std::cout << "\ndo_something with xvalue:\n\n";
    string u = do_something(std::move(x));
#endif
    std::cout << "\ndo_something with prvalue:\n\n";
    string v = do_something(source());
}
```

For me this outputs:

```
$ clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -DPROCESS=1 test.cpp
$ a.out
do_something with lvalue:

string(const string&)
string(string&&)

do_something with xvalue:

string(string&&)
string(string&&)

do_something with prvalue:

string(string&&)
$ clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -DPROCESS=2 test.cpp
$ a.out
do_something with lvalue:

string(const string&)

do_something with xvalue:

string(string&&)

do_something with prvalue:

string(string&&)
```

The table below summarizes my results (using clang -std=c++11). The first number is the number of copy constructions and the second number is the number of move constructions:

```
+----+--------+--------+---------+
|    | lvalue | xvalue | prvalue |
+----+--------+--------+---------+
| p1 |  1/1   |  0/2   |   0/1   |
+----+--------+--------+---------+
| p2 |  1/0   |  0/1   |   0/1   |
+----+--------+--------+---------+
```

The pass-by-value solution requires only one overload but costs an extra move construction when passing lvalues and xvalues.  This may or may not be acceptable for any given situation.  Both solutions have advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: std::string is a standard library class. It already is both moveable and copyable. I don't see how this is relevant. The OP is asking more about the performance of move vs. *references*, not the performance of move vs. copy.

Comment: This answer counts the number of moves and copies a std::string will undergo under the pass-by-value design described by both Herb and Dave, vs passing by reference with a pair of overloaded functions.  I use the OP's code in the demo, except for substituting in a dummy string to shout-out when it is getting copied/moved.

Comment: You should probably optimize the code before performing the tests…

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant:  Did you get different results?  If so, using what compiler with what command line arguments?

Answer (score 16):

Herb Sutter is still on record, along with Bjarne Stroustroup, in recommending `const std::string&` as a parameter type; see https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rf-in .

There is a pitfall not mentioned in any of the other answers here: if you pass a string literal to a `const std::string&` parameter, it will pass a reference to a temporary string, created on-the-fly to hold the characters of the literal.  If you then save that reference, it will be invalid once the temporary string is deallocated. To be safe, you must save a *copy*, not the reference. The problem stems from the fact that string literals are `const char[N]` types, requiring promotion to `std::string`.

The code below illustrates the pitfall and the workaround, along with a minor efficiency option -- overloading with a `const char*` method, as described at [Is there a way to pass a string literal as reference in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27365824/is-there-a-way-to-pass-a-string-literal-as-reference-in-c/27365886#27365886).

(Note: Sutter & Stroustroup advise that if you keep a copy of the string, also provide an overloaded function with a && parameter and std::move() it.)

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
class WidgetBadRef {
public:
    WidgetBadRef(const std::string& s) : myStrRef(s)  // copy the reference...
    {}

    const std::string& myStrRef;    // might be a reference to a temporary (oops!)
};

class WidgetSafeCopy {
public:
    WidgetSafeCopy(const std::string& s) : myStrCopy(s)
            // constructor for string references; copy the string
    {std::cout << "const std::string& constructor\n";}

    WidgetSafeCopy(const char* cs) : myStrCopy(cs)
            // constructor for string literals (and char arrays);
            // for minor efficiency only;
            // create the std::string directly from the chars
    {std::cout << "const char * constructor\n";}

    const std::string myStrCopy;    // save a copy, not a reference!
};

int main() {
    WidgetBadRef w1("First string");
    WidgetSafeCopy w2("Second string"); // uses the const char* constructor, no temp string
    WidgetSafeCopy w3(w2.myStrCopy);    // uses the String reference constructor
    std::cout << w1.myStrRef << "\n";   // garbage out
    std::cout << w2.myStrCopy << "\n";  // OK
    std::cout << w3.myStrCopy << "\n";  // OK
}
```

OUTPUT:

> ```
> const char * constructor
> const std::string& constructor
>
> Second string
> Second string
> ```

Comment: This is a different issue and WidgetBadRef doesn't need to have a const& parameter to go wrong.  The question is if WidgetSafeCopy just took a string parameter would it be slower?  (I think the copy temporary to member is certainly easier to spot)

Answer (score 16):

See [“Herb Sutter "Back to the Basics! Essentials of Modern C++ Style”](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xnqTKD8uD64).  Among other topics, he reviews the parameter passing advice that’s been given in the past, and new ideas that come in with C++11 and specifically looks at the idea of passing strings by value.

[image: slide 24]

The benchmarks show that passing `std::string`s by value, in cases where the function will copy it in anyway, can be significantly slower!

This is because you are forcing it to always make a full copy (and then move into place), while the `const&` version will update the old string which may reuse the already-allocated buffer.

See his slide 27:  For “set” functions, option 1 is the same as it always was.  Option 2 adds an overload for rvalue reference, but this gives a combinatorial explosion if there are multiple parameters.

It is only for “sink” parameters where a string must be created (not have its existing value changed) that the pass-by-value trick is valid.  That is, **constructors** in which the parameter directly initializes the member of the matching type.

If you want to see how deep you can go in worrying about this, watch [Nicolai Josuttis’s](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PNRju6_yn3o) presentation and good luck with that (*“Perfect — Done!”* n times after finding fault with the previous version.  Ever been there?)

---

This is also summarized as [⧺F.15](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#f15-prefer-simple-and-conventional-ways-of-passing-information) in the Standard Guidelines.

---

## update

Generally, you want to declare "string" parameters as `std::string_view` (by **value**).  This allows you to pass an existing `std::string` object as efficiently as with `const std::string&`, and also pass a lexical string literal (like `"hello!"`) without copying it, and pass objects of type `string_view` which is necessary now that those are in the ecosystem too.

The exception is when the function needs an actual `std::string` instance, in order to pass to another function that's declared to take `const std::string&`.

Answer (score 8):

IMO using the C++ reference for `std::string` is a quick and short local optimization, while using passing by value could be (or not) a better global optimization.

So the answer is: it depends on circumstances:

1. If you write all the code from the outside to the inside functions, you know what the code does, you can use the reference `const std::string &`.
2. If you write the library code or use heavily library code where strings are passed, you likely gain more in global sense by trusting `std::string` copy constructor behavior.

Answer (score 3):

As @JDługosz points out in the comments, Herb gives other advice in another (later?) talk, see roughly from here: https://youtu.be/xnqTKD8uD64?t=54m50s.

His advice boils down to only using value parameters for a function `f` that takes so-called sink arguments, assuming you will move construct from these sink arguments.

This general approach only adds the overhead of a move constructor for both lvalue and rvalue arguments compared to an optimal implementation of `f` tailored to lvalue and rvalue arguments respectively. To see why this is the case, suppose `f` takes a value parameter, where `T` is some copy and move constructible type:

```
void f(T x) {
  T y{std::move(x)};
}
```

Calling `f` with an lvalue argument will result in a copy constructor being called to construct `x`, and a move constructor being called to construct `y`. On the other hand, calling `f` with an rvalue argument will cause a move constructor to be called to construct `x`, and another move constructor to be called to construct `y`.

In general, the optimal implementation of `f` for lvalue arguments is as follows:

```
void f(const T& x) {
  T y{x};
}
```

In this case, only one copy constructor is called to construct `y`. The optimal implementation of `f` for rvalue arguments is, again in general, as follows:

```
void f(T&& x) {
  T y{std::move(x)};
}
```

In this case, only one move constructor is called to construct `y`.

So a sensible compromise is to take a value parameter and have one extra move constructor call for either lvalue or rvalue arguments with respect to the optimal implementation, which is also the advice given in Herb's talk.

As @JDługosz pointed out in the comments, passing by value only makes sense for functions that will construct some object from the sink argument. When you have a function `f` that copies its argument, the pass-by-value approach will have more overhead than a general pass-by-const-reference approach. The pass-by-value approach for a function `f` that retains a copy of its parameter will have the form:

```
void f(T x) {
  T y{...};
  ...
  y = std::move(x);
}
```

In this case, there is a copy construction and a move assignment for an lvalue argument, and a move construction and move assignment for an rvalue argument. The most optimal case for an lvalue argument is:

```
void f(const T& x) {
  T y{...};
  ...
  y = x;
}
```

This boils down to an assignment only, which is potentially much cheaper than the copy constructor plus move assignment required for the pass-by-value approach. The reason for this is that the assignment might reuse existing allocated memory in `y`, and therefore prevent (de)allocations, whereas the copy constructor will usually allocate memory.

For an rvalue argument the most optimal implementation for `f` that retains a copy has the form:

```
void f(T&& x) {
  T y{...};
  ...
  y = std::move(x);
}
```

So, only a move assignment in this case. Passing an rvalue to the version of `f` that takes a const reference only costs an assignment instead of a move assignment. So relatively speaking, the version of `f` taking a const reference in this case as the general implementation is preferable.

So in general, for the most optimal implementation, you will need to overload or do some kind of perfect forwarding as shown in the talk. The drawback is a combinatorial explosion in the number of overloads required, depending on the number of parameters for `f` in case you opt to overload on the value category of the argument. Perfect forwarding has the drawback that `f` becomes a template function, which prevents making it virtual, and results in significantly more complex code if you want to get it 100% right (see the talk for the gory details).

Comment: See Herb Sutter’s findings in my new answer:  only do that when you move *construct*, not move assign.

Comment: @JDługosz, thanks for the pointer to Herb's talk, I just watched it and completely revised my answer. I was not aware of the (move) assign advice.

Comment: that figure and advice is in the [Standard Guidelines document](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#f15-prefer-simple-and-conventional-ways-of-passing-information), now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that "const" is a non-granular qualifier.   What is usually meant by "const string ref" is "don't modify this string", not "don't modify the reference count".   There is simply no way, in C++, to say *which* members are "const".   They either all are, or none of them are.

In order to hack around this language issue, STL *could* allow "C()" in your example to make a move-semantic copy *anyway*, and dutifully ignore the "const" with regard to the reference count (mutable).   As long as it was well-specified, this would be fine.

Since STL doesn't, I have a version of a string that const_casts<> away the reference counter (no way to retroactively make something mutable in a class hierarchy), and - lo and behold - you can freely pass cmstring's as const references, and make copies of them in deep functions, all day long, with no leaks or issues.

Since C++ offers no "derived class const granularity" here, writing up a good specification and making a shiny new "const movable string" (cmstring) object is the best solution I've seen.

Comment: @BenVoigt yep... instead of casting away, it should be mutable... but you can't change an STL member to mutable in a derived class.

Comment: It sounds like you have a cool solution to... something, but I'm not sure what the something is.  Perhaps you could add some introductory sentences to make it clear what the connection is between the question ("I heard a recent talk by Herb Sutter who suggested that the reasons to pass std::vector and std::string by const & are largely gone. ... Can anyone explain why Herb might have said this?") to the start of your answer ("The problem is that "const" is a non-granular qualifier. ...")