# Unable to debug the string conversion thing in C++ code

Tags: c++, string, c++11

I am new to C++ OOP concepts. The problem I am having currently with the string declaration in getter and setter function. I use eclipse IDE and the error I get is

> `error: cannot convert 'Student::getname' from type 'std::__cxx11::string (Student::)() {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> (Student::)()}' to type 'std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}'`
>   `return getname;`

The code is as follows:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;

class Student
{
private:
    int rollno;
    string name;
    string school;
public:

void setrollno(int i)
{
    rollno =i;
}
void setname(string n)
{
    name =n;
}
void setschool(string s)
{
    school =s;
}
int getrollno()
    {
        return rollno;
    }
string getname()
{
    return getname;
}
string getschool()
{
    return school;
}
};
int main()
{
    Student A;
    A.setrollno(3);
    cout << A.getrollno();
    A.setname("vinod");
    cout << A.getname();
    A.setschool("carmel");
    cout << A.getschool();
}
```

Could anyone tell me what the problem is?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. When entering your question please use the preview to see how it appears, and format code correctly using the formatting controls above the input box. Your original question was not displaying correctly and had to be fixed.

Comment: `return getname;` Is that what you intended?

Comment: Stop using accessors once and for all.

Comment: @NathanCooper: `return name;` is that what you intended? Your comment's code is exactly the same as in the question ;)

Comment: Replace `#include<string.h>` with `#include<string>`. `string.h` only declares the c-functions for character array manipulation.

Answer (score 5):

The name of your name member variable is `name` and not `getname`. You should change the `getname()` function to return the proper member variable:

```
string getname()
{
    return name;
}
```

Also I suggest that you look at `const` and reference to improve your code. for example you could return/pass some `const` reference (`&`) to avoid copy. Here is a good post that explains it: [Passing std::string by Value or Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10789740/passing-stdstring-by-value-or-reference)