# I need a secondary opinion on the outputting of calculations and with using get.line in a for loop with 5 consecutive repetitions

Tags: c++

Good day

I have written a code that outputs a payslip for an employee.

Also despite doing lots of research (i have tried to figure it out on my own) I am not sure how to get my for loop to allow me to consecutively enter information for 5 different employees on the same output screen. When i run the program it allows me to enter all the information for the pay slip except the name of the employees at the beginning of each new pay slip.

I am a beginner wanting to learn as much as possible so any explanation would be greatly appreciated.

My code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

 using namespace std;

 void getData (string & theEmployee , float & theHoursWorked, float & 
 thePayRate)
{
 cout<< "Enter the employees name and surname: "<< endl;
 getline(cin, theEmployee);

 cout << "Enter the numbers of hours the employee worked: " << endl;
 cin >> theHoursWorked;

 cout << "Enter the employees hourly pay rate?" << endl;
 cin >> thePayRate;

}

 float calculatePay(const string & theEmployee, float theHoursWorked, float 
 thePayRate)
{
float regularPay, thePay, overtimeHours;
if (theHoursWorked > 40)
{
 regularPay = 40 * thePayRate;
 overtimeHours = theHoursWorked - 40;
 thePay = regularPay + (overtimeHours * 1.5 * thePayRate);
   return thePay
}
 else
 thePay = theHoursWorked * thePayRate;
 return thePay;
}

void printPaySlip(const string & theEmployee, float theHoursWorked, float
thePayRate, float thePay)
{
 float overtimeHours;
 cout << "Pay slip for " << theEmployee <<endl;
 cout << "Hours worked: "<< theHoursWorked << endl;
 if (theHoursWorked > 40)
 overtimeHours = theHoursWorked - 40;
 else
 overtimeHours = 0;
 cout << "Overtime hours: "<< overtimeHours << endl;
 cout << "Hourly pay rate: " << thePayRate << endl;
 cout << "Pay: " << thePay << endl;
 cout << endl;

}


  int main()
{
   string theEmployee;
   float theHoursWorked;
   float thePayRate;
   int thePay;

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
 getData(theEmployee, theHoursWorked, thePayRate);
 thePay = calculatePay (theEmployee, theHoursWorked, thePayRate);
 printPaySlip(theEmployee, theHoursWorked, thePayRate, thePay);
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would never work overtime under your rules.  You're giving $1.50/hr for overtime, instead of 1.5 times the regular pay rate.

Comment: Thank you, i see where my error is now. I would hate to work under my rules to.

Comment: any idea on the loop?

Answer (score 0):

As for the overtime, as pointed out in the comments, you've missed multiplying by the payrate.

```
 if (theHoursWorked > 40)
 {
    regularPay = 40 * thePayRate;
    overtimeHours = theHoursWorked - 40;
    thePay = regularPay + (overtimeHours * 1.5 * regularPay);
    return thePay
 } else {
    thePay = theHoursWorked * thePayRate;
 }
 return thePay;
}
```

As for the entering the name, if you can enter the payrate and such for the later employees, then you may want to use the same code for all 3.

```
cin >> theEmployee;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you got those '*' near some of your lines but here's what you should change:

Pass strings by const reference and not by value like this ([see here why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10789740/passing-stdstring-by-value-or-reference)):

```
float calculatePay(const string & theEmployee, float theHoursWorked, float thePayRate)

void printPaySlip(const string & theEmployee, float theHoursWorked, float
                   thePayRate, float thePay)
```

Get rid of the weird asterisks, add ".f" at the end of some of the float variables (nitpicking now), the function calculatePay() doesn't need "theEmployee" string since you don't use it inside the function body.

Comment: Thank you. I have edited my code however it will still not allow me to enter the employees name.

Comment: Maybe add "cin.get();" before the line "getline(cin, theEmployee);" ?

Comment: then it just stops me from running the output altogether