# const reference parameter with default value

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, static, default-value

I have one class with a constructor that takes another struct as a parameter, and that has a default value. Something like this:

```
class A
{
public:
A(someStruct st = someStruct::defaultStruct());
};
```

I've run a static analyzer on my code and it says that this parameter should be const ref. But it's kinda ref to a temporary, though I'm making a copy of it the the constructor, but still I'm confused should I do it const ref.

someStruct::defaultStruct() is something like

```
static someStruct someStruct::defaultStruct()
{
    return { 0, 0 };
}
```

Comment: Depends of `someStruct`. (size, trivial copy/destructor)?

Comment: @Jarod42 someStruct doesn't have a cope constructor and d-tor, it has few fields including other template structs with simple constructors also without d-tor and other

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Related: [pass-by-value-or-const-reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18659043/pass-by-value-or-const-reference). Default argument doesn't matter.

Comment: @eerorika I'm concerning about having reference to a temporary in this case. Though it won't go out of scope, and later in my c-tor I will make a copy out of it, but could it be possible downside or maybe it's just a terrible bad style, like using goto, for ex.

Comment: const ref is not problematic here, and is a good default.

Answer (score 0):

Analyzer says it needs to be `const&` because `someStruct::defaultStruct()` returns a temporary value. You need a code like this:

```
A(const someStruct& st = someStruct::defaultStruct());
```

Because only `const&` can bind to temporary as a default value for your argument.

Comment: @Jarod42 No it is not. And he says his *analyzer* says this, not compiler. But in general, code should be like this.