# Can you dynamically allocate a vector?

Tags: c++, memory, vector, stl

I need my vector container to persist past the end of the function that allocates it.

```
void initVector() {
    vector<obj1*> R;
}
```

Why is this not valid?

```
void initVector() {
    vector<obj1*> R = new vector<obj1*>;
}
```

Comment: Could you not just return it?

Comment: Why do you need to do that? And how do you intend to prevent a memory leak?

Comment: Can't you just pass an empty vector as reference and do what you need to do in the function?

Comment: Good question, but I agree with @juanchopanza. However, if you had to do it, it isn't valid because `new` returns a handle to the allocated memory. All you need to do to make it valid is to make `R` a pointer of type `std::vector<obj>`. Just like everyone is saying make sure you don't have a memory leak if you do call `new` make sure to call `delete` correctly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should be `vector<obj1*>* R = new vector<obj1*>;`. However, with C++11's move semantics, using pointers or references to avoid expensive copies is usually not needed. In the case of a `vector`, the below code doesn't copy `tempVec` - it will move it at least. More likely that compiler will elide the copy. You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10231349/are-the-days-of-passing-const-stdstring-as-a-parameter-over).

```
vector<obj1*> getVector()
{
 vector<obj1*> tempVec;
 //populate tempVec;
 return tempVec;//The standard guarantees a move at least. Compilers are free to elide this copy.
}
```

EDIT : As @juanchopanza points out in the comments, if you have a good reason to be doing this, be wary of managing the lifetime of the vector allocated on the heap, `R`. This isn't an issue specific to this statement - it applies to dynamically allocated structures in general. However, it might need special mention here since you have a `vector` of pointers. In addition to correctly managing the lifetime of `R`, you also need to carefully manage the lifetimes of the `obj1*` it contains. Objects allocated on the heap don't get deleted when the pointer holding them goes out of scope. You will have to manually call `delete` on a pointer to that memory location when you are done using it. This applies both to the `vector* R` and, unless owned by some other part of your program, to the `obj*` that it contains.

Comment: And then they have a memory leak.

Comment: That's a weird assumption. The issue OP had was with that line of code. That was the question and that is what this answers. Your comment is like saying "You will have a memory leak" to someone asking a question about the syntax of `new`. I am not suggesting that they `new` the `vector` and leave it there, without bothering to clean it or worry about the pointers it contains.

Comment: @Pradhan: The point of the question is to get a valid `std::vector` even after the end of the function. With your implementation, either he will not `delete` the `vector` properly, leaving a memory leak, or he will `delete` it properly and not have what he wants (a valid `vector`). Either way, your approach doesn't help him.

Comment: It's not a weird assumption given that OP clearly doesn't know basic things such as `new` returns a pointer.

Comment: This seems to be what I'm looking for. Can you explain why this statement leaks memory?

Comment: @R1v2 Edited with more details.