# Does the compiler perform return value optimisation in case of returning member variable?

Tags: c++, reference, copy-constructor, temporary-objects

Given the following code

```
class foo
{
    private:
        boost::shared_ptr <std::deque<foo> > m_ptr;
    public:
        foo();
        boost::shared_ptr <std::deque<foo> > get_my_ptr()
        {
            return m_ptr;
        }
};
```

And when we call `get_my_ptr()` function like this

```
boost::shared_ptr <std::deque<foo> > ptr = get_my_ptr()
```

Does the compiler call copy constructor to create ptr object or it can perform nrvo?
And what is the difference we we call it like this

```
const boost::shared_ptr <std::deque<foo> >& ptr = get_my_ptr()
```

Comment: What exactly is `boost::shared`? I am only familiar with `boost::shared_ptr<>`, and am somewhat confused as to why you would be holding a member variable "shared", and then go ahead and pass it out to callers...?!?

Comment: Sorry I have corrected the code.

Comment: OK, forget my (now deleted) comment. I have *no* idea what you are trying to do there. A class `foo` holding a shared pointer to `std::deque< foo >` and passing that out on request?

Comment: Maybe remove the shared_ptr altogether and use a type `Foo`. The actual type of the object you're returning has no effect on whether NRVO happens or not.

Comment: It's a good question but the worked example throws up a whole lot of other issues. The answer, of course, is 'no it can't'. Shallow copying a member variable would not end well. Returning a const reference suitably burdens the caller with making the deep copy choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With NRVO, the compiler is allowed to omit copy- and move-construction if
the return statement's expression is the name of a local, non-volatile object with automatic storage duration, which is not a function parameter. That local object is constructed directly in the storage where the function's return value would otherwise be copied to. 
These conditions are not met for member variables. I's only possible if you created a local copy of the member:

```
boost::shared_ptr<std::deque<foo>> get_my_ptr()
{
    auto p = m_ptr;
    return p;
}
```

In your example the copy ctor will be called, which will increase the reference counter of the shared pointer. The same will happen if you bind the returned  object to a const reference.

Comment: There's another limitation, which doesn't apply in this case: the local cannot be a parameter of the function.

Comment: @juanchopanza in this case? do you mean `this` parameter?

Comment: No, I mean in *this example*, in OP's case. Not the C++ `this`.

Comment: @juanchopanza yes, but in **this** case, there is only the `this` parameter :-)

Comment: That's why if doesn't apply in *this* case :-) I with they had called it `self`...

Comment: Worth mentioning that on a more abstract level, NRVO applies to cases where the return value is created within the function, and thus can be created inside the space supplied by the caller. But the member variable already exists before the function call.

Answer (score 2):

A compile must not perform RVO when a member variable is returned. If it did, the object will be left with an invalid member.

Comment: "If it did" is borderline metaphysical. You could also imagine the object would end up sharing its member with the caller somehow.

Comment: @juanchopanza, that will be interesting trek for the member variable -- being shared by the caller and the object.