# How can i make a vector of pointers that point to dynamically allocated object?

Tags: c++, vector

I want to create a vector of pointers that each point to their own Martian object but i can't figure out how to arrange it. I'm currently getting the error

> Non-const lvalue reference to type 'vector' cannot bind to a value of unrelated type 'martianDatabase'

but the error constantly changes with every change i make. I've watched a ton of tutorials the last two days trying to figure this out but I'm still stuck.

```
struct Martian
{
    Martian(string fname, string lname, string ssid);
    string fname, lname, ssid;
    ~Martian();
};


class martianDatabase
{
    vector<Martian*> database;
    martianDatabase();
    void addMartian(vector <Martian*> &database, int &iterator, string f,  string l, string id);
    int iterator = 0;
};

Martian::Martian(string f, string l, string id)
{
    fname = f;
    lname = l;
    ssid = id;
}

void martianDatabase::addMartian(vector <Martian*> &database, int &i, string f, string l, string id)
{
    Martian* m = new Martian(f, l, id);
    database[i].push_back(m);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: This `Martian::Martian(string f, string l, string id)` would be better as `Martian::Martian(const string& f, const string& l, const string& id)` - Saves copying

Comment: Also the use of smart pointers might make your life a bit easier

Comment: thank you, changed but the my dilemma remains

Comment: " the error constantly changes with every change i make." - you need to figure out what causes the error, and fix it.  Randomly changing the program and hoping to see if the error goes away, isn't a good idea. Even if you do happen to make the error go away, the code might still have a bug

Comment: @EdHeal passing by value will be more efficient in some cases

Comment: @M.M - In some cases - but not for strings

Comment: Really - Having to invoke the copy constructor i.e. allocate memory, copy or a reference?

Comment: @EdHeal [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10231349/are-the-days-of-passing-const-stdstring-as-a-parameter-over) for discussion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things wrong with your code:

- You shouldn't pass your `vector<Martian*>` as an argument to `addMartian`, instead you can just access it through the `this` pointer.
- There is no need for your `int& iterator`, as all you are trying to do is add your `Martian` to the end of a vector
- Your code `database[i].push_back(m);` gets the i’th element of the vector `database`, which is a `Martian&`, and then trys to call `push_back(m)` on it, which is not possible, as there is no such function declared for type `Martian`, what you probably wanted is `database.push_back(m)`, which insert `m` at the back of the `database` vector

Consider the following alternative:

```
class martianDatabase
{
    vector<Martian*> database;
    martianDatabase();
    void addMartian(string f,  string l, string id);
};

void martianDatabase::addMartian(string f, string l, string id)
{
    this->database.push_back(new Martian(f, l, id));
}
```

Though not realy a problem, it is potentially better to directly initialise member in your constructor (where possible) rather then copy assign them, i.e. use the code:

```
Martian::Martian(string f, string l, string id) : fname(f), lname(l), ssid(id) { }
```

Comment: You do not need `this->`. Also smart pointers - in fact why use pointers at all!

Comment: @EdHeal, I was only using it to emphasis where the `database` came from, the current object as opposed to a parameter. As to your remark about pointers, if you are referring to `this` being a pointer, I agree it's stupid, it should be a reference. If you are referring to `database` being a vector of pointers, yes it is pointless in this situation, but it is what the OP wanted, I assumed that the OP needed it to be a pointer, for example if he wants to be able to store objects of derived classes in the array, or he want's to later manually delete the Martians without removing from the database.

Comment: @Isaac i just realized that i don't want to push_back, i want to set database[i] = m. Would i still remove my int i in this case?

Comment: @Ammar I am unsure as to why you would want to do that, but in this case you would add an `int i` parameter to the `addMartian` function I gave you, and change the code to `this->database[i] = new Martian(f, l, id);` (MAKE SURE you check that `this->database.size() > i`, If it isn't you probably want to use `push_back`).

Comment: That change gives me         No viable overloaded '='

Comment: @Ammar that's very odd, it should work perfectly, I'm sorry but I have no idead why. (Annother note: `this->database[i] = new Martian(f, I, id)` will replace whatever was previously there, so you may want to delete the original value first, NOTE: I don't know how you plan on using your martianDatabase class so my suggestions may be inapparopriate.)

Comment: @Ammar does your error message give any more details?

Comment: thats all it says. Google says i have to stick const on something because a temporary object cannot bind to a non const reference. I don't know if thats relevant to my code though.

Comment: Are you sure your using my code exactly as I said? Sorry but my compiler is corrently reinstalling, so I can't test it...

Comment: oh, no your code works perfectly fine, i was just trying to implement it into my code. Thanks a ton

Comment: sorry, how would i access an element of the object that the i-th pointer from my database is pointing to?

Comment: Like this: `this->database[i]->lname`, or if you want the entire Martian object, then `*this->database[i]`

Answer (score 1):

```
vector<Martian*> database;
```

Your `database` is a `std::vector` of pointers to `Martian` objects. That's what this declaration states.

```
database[i].push_back(m);
```

Since `database` is a vector, `database[i]` would be the `i`th value in this vector. Since this vector is a vector of `Martian *`, therefore `database[i]` is some `Martian *` value in this vector.

Obviously, you understand that if you have `Martian *`, a pointer to a Martian, it's not a class, and you can't `push_back`() anything on it. It's a pointer. A plain, garden variety pointer. You can't `push_back()` anything to a pointer. You can't `begin()` or `end()` it, etc...

That's what the compiler is telling you, with it's error message.

And, as far as your "How can i make a vector of pointers" question, you already did it:

```
vector<Martian *> database;
```

That's a vector of pointers. Now, whether it's a vector of pointers to dynamically-allocated objects, or not, that's no longer relevant. The vector doesn't care where the objects it's pointing to come from. A pointer to a dynamically-allocated object is exactly the same as a pointer to some object in a `static` scope.

Comment: Ah so it would be         database[i] = m;

Comment: That would be valid C++ code, that should compile without any issues. Whether this will do what you really want it to do, is a completely separate question.