# Passing by const reference or utilize move semantics

Tags: c++, parameter-passing, move, c++17, move-semantics

In the past I was taught that when passing `std::string` to a function or even a constructor to pass by `const reference` instead of passing by value due to copy.

**example 1:** - *function parameter*

```
void someFunc( const std::string& str1, const std::string& str2 ) {
    // some code
}
```

**example 2:** - *constructor argument*

```
class Foo {
private:
    std::string str1_;
    std::string str2_;

public:
    Foo( const std::string& str1, const std::string& str2 ) :
      str1_( str1 ),
      str2_( str2 ),
    {}

    // other methods or functions
};
```

With modern `C++` we now have move semantics; I'm not 100% sure for function parameters as of yet but I'm guessing they should relatively be the same as class constructor arguments: And Foo from above simply becomes:

```
class Foo {
private:
    std::string str1_;
    std::string str2_;

public:
    Foo( std::string str1, std::string str2 ) :
      str1_ { std::move( str1 ) },
      str2_ { std::move( str2 ) }
    {}

    // other methods or functions
};
```

Are there specific cases where one method is favored over the other; or should the old way of being taught `pass string as const reference` now be discarded and just use pass by direct object and use `move semantics` instead? If so what is the overall trade offs or benefits of the later over the previous way of doing things in `C++`? If not, then what's the point of new features such as move semantics? Or does it depend on individual situations? Mainly looking for some definitive clarity.

I do believe that the 2<sup>nd</sup> case of `Foo` should at the least fulfill `RAII` and that is not what I'm pertaining to either.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10231349/are-the-days-of-passing-const-stdstring-as-a-parameter-over ; looked also at the linked/related questions

Comment: @Mat The link to the question was fairly close; and I got a very good dose of mixed answers, reviews, suggestions and guidelines from it; so I'm back to square one by not having a definitive clarity... lol

Comment: You get a lot of different answers because there isn't one option that is always better than the others. Depends on your use cases. (And as always: use the simplest thing first. If it's a bottleneck, investigate and go for more complicated things.)

Comment: https://youtu.be/_nrly6PH6NU?t=1m37s