# Simpler way to create a SWIG typemap for a function with multiple arguments?

Tags: c++, lua, swig, typemaps

Here's the C++ function that I want to wrap using SWIG.

```
static void my_func(t_string name, t_string value)
{
    do_something(name, value);
}
```

And here are the SWIG typemaps.

```
%typemap(in) (t_string name)
{
    if (!lua_isstring(L, $input)) {
      SWIG_exception(SWIG_RuntimeError, "argument mismatch: string expected");
    }
    $1 = lua_tostring(L, $input);
}

%typemap(in) (t_string value)
{
    if (!lua_isstring(L, $input)) {
      SWIG_exception(SWIG_RuntimeError, "argument mismatch: string expected");
    }
    $1 = lua_tostring(L, $input);
}
```

This way, I could successfully use `my_func` in Lua.

But I wonder if there's any simpler solution than this since the above 2 typemaps are identical but only use different name.

Let's say if I later have a C++ function that takes 3 `t_string` arguments, then should I add one more typemap using different name?
Or would there be any simpler solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing it wrong.  You are using a multi-argument typemap for a single type.  Remove the variable name (and optionally the parentheses) from `t_string`.  This is explained in details in the section about [pattern matching](http://swig.org/Doc3.0/Typemaps.html#Typemaps_nn5) in the chapter for typemaps of the documentation.

```
%module typemaptest

%typemap(in) t_string
{
    if (!lua_isstring(L, $input)) {
      SWIG_exception(SWIG_RuntimeError, "argument mismatch: string expected");
    }
    $1 = lua_tostring(L, $input);
}

void my_func(t_string name, t_string value);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works like a charm. But is it not possible to create nameless typemap for multiple arguments? For example, I use `%typemap(in) (int argc, t_atom *argv)` to pass lua-table to C++ function. I just tried changing this to `%typemap(in) (int, t_atom*)` but it didn't work. So maybe it's only possible to do pattern matching with single argument functions?

Comment: I will give you a bounty tomorrow.

Comment: @ZackLee I guess the design decision for requiring names for multi-parameter typemaps is, that otherwise they get too greedy and match in situations where they shouldn't.  However, it is easy to duplicate the multi-arg typemap for other variable names using e.g. `%typemap(in) (int num_args, t_atom *args) = (int argc, t_atom *argv);` (assuming a multi-arg typemap for `(int argc, t_atom *argv)` exists).

Comment: Thank you. I would appreciate if you could take a look at my question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50896799/is-it-possible-to-require-a-script-that-is-loaded-using-lual-loadstring