# Is it possible to require() a script that is loaded using luaL_loadstring()?

Tags: module, lua, require

I'm a beginner in Lua.

I wonder if it is possible to use `require('filename')` to require a script that is loaded using `luaL_loadstring()`.

Since `luaL_loadstring(lua_State *L, const char *s)` doesn't specify any filename, I don't know how to use `require()` to load this script from other script.

Does `require()` only works with actual `.lua` files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`luaL_loadstring` creates a Lua function which, when called, executes the string it was given.  We can use this fact, because Lua C modules also simply call a function `luaopen_MODULE`.  This function returns a table with the module content.  That is to say, if we want to load a module via `luaL_loadstring` the script given as a string *has to return a table*.  The only thing left to do is letting the interpreter know where to find the module.  Therefore we simply create an entry in `package.preload`.

The interesting part is between the dashes.  The rest is just boilerplate to get the interpreter running.  (Might not work in 5.1)

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#include <lua.h>
#include <lualib.h>
#include <lauxlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <script.lua>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    lua_State * L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);

    // ---- Register our "fromstring" module ----
    lua_getglobal(L, "package");
    lua_getfield(L, -1, "preload");
    luaL_loadstring(L, "return { test = function() print('Test') end }");
    lua_setfield(L, -2, "fromstring");
    // ------------------------------------------

    if (luaL_dofile(L, argv[1]) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr,"lua: %s\n", lua_tostring(L, -1));
        lua_close(L);
        return 1;
    }

    lua_close(L);
}
```

Input script:

```lua
local fromstring = require("fromstring")
fromstring.test()
```

Output:

```
Test
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, take a peek into [the documentation for `require()`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-require), and you will see it's very flexible.

The relevant parts are:

1. `package.loaded[modname]`. Just set it with the module name you want. Be sure to set it before you `require` it though.
2. `package.searchers` and the default entries therein. This is only relevant if the module is not registered as loaded as noted above.

In more detail:

If you want to set up a package for require to find it, you have two choices: 1. Set it up as fully loaded by adding it to `package.loaded`, or 2. make sure it's found by one of the `package.searchers`-entries.
[Any competent lua modules tutorial](http://lua-users.org/wiki/ModulesTutorial) will tell you how to structure the module itself easily, the docs give you the mechanics of why too.
[The registry, which contains an entry for the global environment](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#2.2), can be accessed from native code, so you can do it from there if you so desire.

Comment: I tried the `package.loaded["modname"]` but it doesn't work. The script loads if I do it like `package.loaded["modname"] = nil`. But then I could not use `require("modname")` from other script. Could you please show me a simple example that works? (how script `a` and `b` should be written for example )

Comment: I followed the tutorial but it doesn't mention how to expose non-file script to be used from other script using `require()` which is what I would like to know.

Comment: I'm sorry I still don't get it.

Comment: @ZackLee: Elaborated.

Comment: I read all your stuffs but still couldn't figure out how to do it. Could you please show me a simple example that works if you really know how to do it? (how script `a` and `b` should be written for example)