# How to access local table variable from other script

Tags: lua

My Code:

```
lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
luaL_openlibs(L);
lua_settop(L, 0);
//Script A
luaL_dostring(L, "A = {} A.num = 3");
//Script B
luaL_dostring(L, "B = {} function B.update() return A.num * 2 end");
//Script C
luaL_dostring(L, "print(B.update())"); 
lua_close(L);
```

The Result: `6`

However if I make the table `A` and `B` local like the following:

```
lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
luaL_openlibs(L);
lua_settop(L, 0);
//Script A
luaL_dostring(L, "local A = {} A.num = 3");
//Script B
luaL_dostring(L, "local B = {} function B.update() return A.num * 2 end");
//Script C
luaL_dostring(L, "print(B.update())"); 
lua_close(L);
```

It doesn't output anything.

How to make the second code work and what is more recommended design between the two?

ADDITIONAL QUESTION: Is putting all functions and variables inside a uniquely named table per `.lua` file a common technique in Lua to avoid name collision between each files?

Comment: Local variables are not accessible from beyond their lexical scope.  And their lexical scope is inside the chunk where they were defined. Each `dostring` introduces separate chunk.

Comment: Always check for errors! `luaL_dostring(L, "print(B.update())");` in second example will fail with something like `failed to index nil global "B"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Luiz Henrique already mentioned, `local` variables cannot be accessed outside their scope and it is impolite to pollute the global environment with hardcoded names.

Instead you could make use of the trick that I have presented already in [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50925130) to another question of yours.  Use `luaL_loadstring` rather than `luaL_dostring` to load the script into a function and register this function as a field in `package.preload`.  Then, inside of your chunks, you can easily `require` the preloaded modules into local variables.

```cpp
#include <lua.hpp>

int main() {
    lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);
    lua_settop(L, 0);

    lua_getglobal(L, "package");
    lua_getfield(L, -1, "preload");

    // Script A
    luaL_loadstring(L, "return { num = 3 }");
    lua_setfield(L, -2, "A");

    // Script B
    luaL_loadstring(L, "local A = require('A')\n"
                       "return { update = function() return A.num * 2 end }");
    lua_setfield(L, -2, "B");

    // Script C
    luaL_dostring(L, "local B = require('B')\n"
                     "print(B.update())");

    lua_close(L);
}
```

That should also answer your additional question: No, use modules as described above.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is great!

Answer (score 5):

Local variables are private to the scripts that define them. That is the whole point.

If you want to export something from a script, return it. Scripts that define libraries typically return a table. This is much more polite than polluting the global environment.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please show me an example by modifying my second example so it can print `6`?