# How to tell if Im using by reference correctly?

Tags: c++, reference, pass-by-reference

So I have a function which sets a variable in a vector and returns a modifiable cell reference back. But I'm unsure if I am using the reference '&' correctly as I have two examples that work. 
Ex1:

```
Cell& Grid::set(const int x, const int y, const Cell & value) {
    int index = get_index(x, y);
    this->grid[index] = value;
    return this->grid[index];
}
```

Ex2:

```
Cell& Grid::set(const int x, const int y, const Cell value) {
    int index = get_index(x, y);
    this->grid[index] = value;
    return this->grid[index];
}
```

Which would be the correct way and how can I tell for the future?

Edit: Cell is an enum not an object

Comment: FYI, you don't need the `this->` syntax, except when differentiating parameter names from member names.

Comment: IMHO, objects should be passed by reference, except when they are not modified, then they are passed by `const` reference.  Otherwise, the compiler will make a copy of the object when passed to the function.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I should have mentioned, Cell isn't an object it is an enum, does this change anything?

Comment: You are missing `;` on the return statements.

Comment: @stark I know its just an example but thanks.

Comment: `Cell& void Grid::set` ?

Comment: @NikosC. I dont understand your question. Edit: Realised your meant the conflicting return type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a sink function for the `value` parameter, because of this:

```
grid[index] = value;
```

So in this case, you should be passing by non-const value and move it into `grid`:

```
Cell& Grid::set(const int x, const int y, Cell value)
{
    grid[get_index(x, y)] = std::move(value);
    return grid[index];
}
```

You should make sure that `Cell` is a movable type though, because if it isn't, it will cost you an extra copy.

This is the common pattern that is used when it comes to sink functions. (Meaning functions that store arguments somewhere that outlives the function call itself.)

Also take a look at [another relevant answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60522974/856199) to a different question on when it's beneficial to pass by reference.