# Moving std::string into capture

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Consider the following example that takes a `msg` and posts it asynchronously.

```
    void sendMessage(std::string msg) {
        runAsync<void>([msg = std::move(msg)] {
            onPostMessage(cookie, msg.c_str());
        });
    };
```

Would the following be faster?

```
void sendMessage(std::string&& msg) {
```

What would be the best options at the calling site?

```
    auto msg = ...
    postMessage(msg);
```

or

```
    auto msg = ...
    postMessage(std::move(msg));
```

Note that `msg` isn't needed after the call anymore.

Will the compiler automatically detect that I am not using `msg` anymore after the call and "move" it?

Comment: EDIT: Ah you tagged with only C++14, nevermind... original comment:
I think `std::string_view` would be better than r-value reference to `std::string`. But otherwise they should be equivalent in speed I reckon (the string will materialize only when actually used as per C++17 rules). However the original version is better because it works fro both l-value and r-value (easier to use). Copy-elision will likely take place as well.

Comment: The point is that at the calling site, the `msg` isn't required after posting it, so I am trying to find the most efficient way to pass it down to finally move it into the capture...

Comment: If you are limited to C++14 than it will vary by compiler as there is no guaranteed copy elision or move elision. However even so I would say using value and std::move is better. Alternatively you may try making the `msg` const that could lead to some optimizaton as well. But there are no guarantees by the standard until C++17...

Comment: How would making it `const std::string msg` affect the final move into the capture?

Comment: If you take by value you need to `std::move` at the calling site to avoid a copy if you are passing in an lvalue as in your example. If you use `std::string&&` as parameter you enforce that an rvalue is passed at the calling site, which could be good depending on your use case.

Comment: Try it in compiler explorer. https://godbolt.org/

Comment: Can you just pass the initializer for `msg` directly to `sendMessage`?

Comment: @user3612643 answers: yes, second, no.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are the days of passing const std::string & as a parameter over?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10231349/are-the-days-of-passing-const-stdstring-as-a-parameter-over)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the following solution:

```
void sendMessage(std::string&& msg) {
    runAsync<void>([msg = std::move(msg)] {
        onPostMessage(cookie, msg.c_str());
    });
};
```

and at the calling site:

```
auto msg = ...
sendMessage(std::exchange(msg, {}));
```

Comment: Why exchange and not move?

Comment: @user3612643 After std::move the msg  becomes valid, but in unspecified state. So, to avoid inadvertent use of the variable after sendMessage, I prefer std::exchange.
See (8) at [link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string)